# Can not install rosinstall because of python version conflict

Tags: ubuntu-lucid, ros-fuerte, rosinstall, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm having troubles installing ROS fuerte on Ubuntu Lucid. I did the installation accordign to the standard installation instructions for fuerte on lucid.
But when installing rosinstall (sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall) I get an error regarding python versions (>2.7 needed but 2.6.5-0ubuntu1 installed).
I read that with Lucid python 2.6 is the standard version. I do not face any troubles while installing rosdep.
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks Johannes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60999/can-not-install-rosinstall-because-of-python-version-conflict/) by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-18**:
Can you post the full apt error (gist.github.com)? It is likely that one of `rosinstall`'s dependencies is now requiring py27.

**Comment by [jmacglashan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4797/jmacglashan/) on 2013-04-30**:
I'm having the same problem. There isn't much more to the error message. It's:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-rosinstall: Depends: python (>= 2.7) but 2.6.5-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a bug in the debian generator which created the python 2.7 dependency.  The package now correctly depends on python>=2.6

It is highly recommended not to use the pip version over the apt version.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1